# How to trigger scheduler job immediately in liferay 6.1.1

Tags: quartz-scheduler, liferay-6

for project needed, I need a button when I click it it will trigger a scheduler job immediately in liferay 6.1.1. I know before liferay 4.2 there is a API JobScheduler.triggerJob() to make it happen. but in the 6.1.1 this API is removed, is there any other way I can do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: And in the QuartzSchedulerEngine I do see many methods like pause, start, resume, update the job but I still don't find any method to trigger the job. am I looking at the wrong class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess better way is to execute your process service method on button click event rather than manually triggering a job. If you already have a job, it can call the same process service method.

However below information can be useful if you want to got with custom schedule a job.

SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule menthod will accept custom trigger. Liferay allows to specify cron express as trigger. You can use below expression to trigger immediately.

```
* * * * * ? *
```

An example code custom scheduler can be found in LayoutServiceImpl.schedulePublishToLive method.
I believe you can do similar with above cron express to invoke a job immediately.

```
Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(
            jobName, groupName, schedulerStartDate, schedulerEndDate, cronText);

SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(
            trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, description,
            DestinationNames.LAYOUTS_LOCAL_PUBLISHER, publisherRequest, 0);
```

Comment: I tested "* * * * ? *" on http://www.cronmaker.com/ but looks like it's invalid but I'll double check in the real environment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the cron expression * * * * ? * is invalid. Is there any expression can invoke a job immediately and just one time job?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a star. It should be 5 stars then '?' and a star. checked in cronmaker.com

Comment: This expression * * * * * ? * will trigger immediately. But it will go on. May be you need to handle it to do only once.

Comment: * * * * * ? * work fine. but it's important to run just once. Is there any way to do this in Liferay? it's easy to do this in quartz but seems not easy in Liferay.

Comment: Functionality of a scheduler is to repeatedly call a job. Be it Simple [Its IntervalTrigger in liferay] or Cron trigger. If you want scheduler to process your request only once then you have to implement it to execute your job only once per request. For example, Once a button clicked you generate unique action ID for that request. When a scheduler run it checks for action ID and process job if it exists and set the action ID status to completed so that it won't be picked up when scheduler invoked again. But I am afraid that using scheduler for handling button action is not the correct way.